# Using javascript function arguments as spring message tag arguments

Tags: javascript, spring, internationalization

I'm trying to put a javascript function argument into a Spring message, and it's failing.

The message file entry:

```
operators.delete.confirm=Are you sure you want to delete {0}?
```

The relevant javascript fragment:

```
var msg = '<spring:message code="operators.delete.confirm" arguments="${username}" javaScriptEscape="true"/>';
console.log ( msg );
console.log ( username );
```

The output I would expect for a username of `103` is `Are you sure you want do delete 103?` but the argument isn't being used. The output of the console log message is:

```
[19:00:14.926] Are you sure you want to delete {0}?
[19:00:14.926] 103
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've realised that this doesn't actually make sense. The Spring message tags are parsed in the JSP page on the server, whereas the javascript variable is only available on the client.